# Spring caching works "live" but not in tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I have a service at work using Spring framework (not Boot!) with a guava cache. I would like to use Spring's own facilities. I can get it to work running the actual app, but in tests the caching doesn't work.

I've recreated the issue in a "minimal" app, see below.

I haven't found anything useful by googling, as far as I can tell I have all the ingredients that all the tutorials say to have.

Would appreciate some help with this. "Use Spring Boot" is unfortunately not a solution/option.

Source code, gradle and dir structure follow: (pom available on request)

Test:

```
package com.somepkg;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//@ComponentScan("com.somepkg")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class SomeTest {
    @Autowired MyApp myApp;

    @Test
    public void testStuff() {
        long start, stop, totalTime;

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        myApp.run("stuff");
        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalTime = stop - start;
        System.out.println("Total: " + totalTime);

        assertThat("Call took too long", totalTime < 1100);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
class TestConfig {
    @Bean MyApp myApp() { return new MyApp(new MyService()); }
    @Bean CacheManager cacheManager() { return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("greeting"); }
}
```

App:

```
package com.somepkg;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableCaching
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (GenericApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Main.class)) {
            MyApp app = applicationContext.getBean(MyApp.class);
            app.run("Spring");
        }
    }

    @Bean CacheManager cacheManager() { return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("greeting"); }
}

@Component
class MyApp {
    private final MyService myService;

    public MyApp(MyService myService) { this.myService = myService; }

    public void run(String message) {
        long start, stop, totalTime;

        System.out.println("First call to service...");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        myService.hello(message);
        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalTime = stop - start;

        System.out.println("Second call to service...");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        myService.hello(message);
        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalTime += stop - start;

        System.out.println("done in " + totalTime);
    }
}

@Component
class MyService {
    @Cacheable("greeting")
    public String hello(String message) {
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) {}
        return "Hello " + message + "!";
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
mainClassName = 'com.somepkg.Main'

run { standardInput = System.in }

repositories { jcenter() }

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.17'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-test:5.3.17'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    implementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2'
}
```

Directory structure:

```
├── build.gradle
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── com
    │           └── somepkg
    │               └── Main.java
    └── test
        └── java
            └── com
                └── somepkg
                    └── SomeTest.java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are constructing the instance of type MyService by hand:

```
@Bean MyApp myApp() { return new MyApp(new MyService()); }
```

You need to let do spring the magic of creating **all** the beans. This way the @Cacheable annotations etc are applied via proxy. Since you are constructing the **MyService** by hand via new MyService(), you go exactly around spring for this single dependency, but this dependency needs the proxying of the methods for the @Cacheable annotation to work

Comment: Thanks! It took me a while to figure out how you meant. I modified the code you quoted to `return new MyApp(myService())` where `myService` is defined as one might "expect", and it worked! Also gave me good leads for how to modify the actual work/production code. Big thanks!